# Problem with links

Tags: custom-link, actionlink

I have a few links on my home page witch shows on tabs. Links looks like /a10/o(example). When i deploy my app from na24 to na34 when i click on that links show me message not enough privileges. When i look on same tab like in na24,they have different ids. In Na24 is a10/o in Na34 is a1k/o,what to do? i get this message.[image]

Answer (score 1):

These initial three chars are object name of any custom object in your org. that is why they are different from one org to another. In your case you between NA24 and NA34.

You need to check profile permission for this object. You should have read permission on this object.

Go to Setup-> Users-> Profile -> Object Name

Comment: I do all permisons before,still same...

Comment: as you are checking that object in NA34 you need to update your link with new created object chars that is a1k/o

Comment: I cant change it cause its managed... Anyone else?

Comment: You need to query for the object/record id and NOT hard code the id. You should really almost never hard code an id into code. This makes it org specific as ids can and will change from org to org.

To get only the object id query for a record of that type and substring the first three chars to build your url.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by other members, ids are org-specific - you should rely on something more robust for your logic, otherwise it can also get way too complex to maintain.

Also a reminder that read permissions for the given object can be given through various approaches:

- [Org-wide defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_sharing.htm&type=5);
- [Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_userprofiles.htm&type=5);
- [Permission sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_overview.htm&type=0).